# В чем причина ошибки при запросе к Smaris api?

Tags: php

Делаю запрос:

```
$url = 'https://my.smartis.bi/api/sites/get';
$access_token = 'token';

$data = array(
    'filters' => array(
        'is_active' => true
    )
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN: ',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
```

ответ:

```
{
    "message": "Redis connection [default] not configured."
}
```

Почему так? Причем тут Redis, если это простой запрос к апи?

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка на стороне сервера, т.е на `my.smartis.bi`

Comment: Да, так и есть, узнал у них